# How can I use the `~` symbol in SCSS files in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I have successfully configured Nuxt to use a CSS file called app.scss by adding the following code to my Nuxt configuration:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  css: ['@/assets/styles/app.scss'],
})
```

However, when I tried to import an SCSS file from a Node module using the @use notation in app.scss, I encountered an error:

```
[vite-node] [plugin:vite:css] [VITE_ERROR] ./assets/styles/app.scss:1:1

Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ ┌ @use "~@neolithic-css/toolkit" as neolithic with
2 │ │ (
3 │ │   $mobile-first: false,
4 │ │ );
  │ └─^
  ╵
  assets/styles/app.scss 1:1  root stylesheet
```

Here is the code I used in app.scss to import the SCSS file:

```
@use "~@neolithic-css/toolkit" as neolithic with (
  $mobile-first: false,
);
```

seems like the loader can't recognize the notation `~` which should point to `node_modules` directory. How can I fix this?

Comment: I think there's a slash missing. Can you try to import it with "~/@neolithic-css/toolkit" or "~/node_modules/@neolithic-css/toolkit"?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that I no longer need to use `~`, as the following code works for me:

```
@use "@neolithic-css/toolkit" as neolithic with (
  $mobile-first: false,
);
```